# .NET Core 1.1 application on Mac and SQL Server connection string

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

I'm having problems in connecting a .NET Core 1.1 application to a remote SQL Server, but only on my Mac because on Windows everything works well.

Said that it's not my application and I'm only trying to make it working, this is my connection string on appsettings.Development.json:

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MesDatabase": "Data Source=x.x.x.x\\BLABLA,49331; Initial Catalog=DBNAME; Uid=sa; Pwd=blablabla"
  }
```

This is the error I get opening the connection:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP
>   Provider, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)

I can't access the server, any idea? I'm almost sure that it's a stupid error on connection string but I cannot find it.

I also tried to create a .udl file on Windows, editing it with correct connection data and taking the resulting connection string opening it with notepad. Nothing, always "connection string is not valid" on Mac.

Comment: It makes no sense to specify both an instance name and a port number. Either specify the instance name, and then let the SQL Server Browser service resolve the port for you, or specify the port, but then leave out the instance name. Note: I have no idea if this is the cause of your error, just an observation that your current use of options isn't meaningful.

Comment: Thank you @JeroenMostert but in this case it's necessary, without it doesn't work on Windows too (Error Locating Server/Instance Specified). Maybe on that machine the service which resolves the port is not running.

Comment: Make sure port 49331 is not blocked by firewall or any other app on MAC

Comment: Are you saying connecting to `tcp:x.x.x.x,49331` fails where `tcp:x.x.x.x\BLABLA,49331` works? Because I'd find that very surprising. SQL Server Browser may not be running or not reachable, but in that case instance names aren't useful anyway.

Comment: Make an odbc connection to the server on the mac, you will likely face the same problems. If you don't, then you could target that odbc instead. Also, is that really the port number? It's in the 'high end random ports' range

Comment: @JeroenMostert excuse me, you were right and you gave the positive answer, I missed the second part. Writing only "x.x.x.x\BLABLA" it doesn't work on Mac and on Windows neither, probably because SQL Server Browser is down on server. Writing "x.x.x.x\\BLABLA,49331" works on Windows but not on Mac (my problem). Writing x.x.x.x,49331 works both on Windows and on Mac. This is the right answer. Thank you so much, I guess you can write the answer.

Comment: Could you test to see if `x.x.x.x\BANANA,49331` works on Windows (that is, an invalid instance name)? My theory is that this will connect successfully. That means some versions of ADO.NET (or more probably the SQL Server native client library) will ignore the instance name when the port number is supplied, and others will give an error when both are supplied. (There's something to say for both behaviors.) If this really is Mac vs. Windows only (same version of .NET Core), that'd be interesting, as it means the inconsistency is only in the platform-specific bits.

Comment: In any case, the error message is needlessly confusing and smacks of a bug -- the upper layer reports that the server is inaccessible, but the TCP layer claims the string is invalid. Which is it? And why would the TCP layer get to decide the string is invalid, anyway? Shouldn't the upper layer have handled that? (Rhetorical questions that might become part of a bug report. :-))

Comment: @JeroenMostert you are right again, if as instance name I try to write a random string on Windows it works anyway because it ignores the instance name.
Interesting bug, in theory I'm using 1.1.2 on both machines, perhaps they already fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jeroen Monstert said:

> It makes no sense to specify both an instance name and a port number.
>   Either specify the instance name, and then let the SQL Server Browser
>   service resolve the port for you, or specify the port, but then leave
>   out the instance name.

My problem was due to the fact that in the connection string I had both the instance name and the port, in combination with a "probably bug" on .NET Core 1.1 because behaviour was different between Mac and Windows. In my case SQL Server Browser was down on the server so I needed to specify the port, and for this reason I had to remove the instance name from the connection string.